# GLSL : Color displays wrong

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have a problem with my color shader.

When I create 5 models and apply my color shader for picking, the last object I added to the render list is rendering in-front of the others.

I think it is because the first object will be rendered to the screen and then the last object overrides the first one's color.

Looking from left to right: [image: Left-to-right]

Looking from right to left: [image: Right-to-left]

I already enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` and `GL_CULL_FACE`
Also `glClearDepth(1.0f)` and `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`

I am using the following shaders:

#### Vertex Shader:

```
#version 120
void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 120
uniform vec3 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your render loop code and the code you use to set up the depth test/func?

Comment: Did you actually allocate a depth buffer in your pixel format? Enabling depth testing and clearing the depth buffer will not do you any good if you forgot something this simple ;) Please paste the actual code where you do all of the things you describe.